# Varnish 6.6.1 unexpected panic : Assert error in sml_trimstore(), storage/storage_simple.c

Tags: varnish

Hy all,

I'm running a new varnish 6.6.1 just for image cache for a few week's now and just yesterday he crashed with this great message :

```
Assert error in sml_trimstore(), storage/storage_simple.c line 493:
  Condition((oc->boc->stevedore_priv) == 0) not true.
version = varnish-6.6.1 revision e6a8c860944c4f6a7e1af9f40674ea78bbdcdc66, vrt api = 13.0
ident = Linux,5.4.0-26-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-sfile,-sdefault,-hcritbit,epoll
now = 1146956.025419 (mono), 1629047811.689088 (real)
```

Has anyone an idea about where to look ?

The configuration is based on a previous varnish 5 configuration and seem's ok for me.

Regard's
Claude

Comment: Can you share your VCL file & the `varnishd` runtime parameters? I'll try to simulate the issue before reporting it upstream. Can you also try it on Varnish 6.0 LTS? See https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish60lts for LTS packages.

Comment: Hi, I can provide you the start parameters : 
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
   -a :6081 \
   -a localhost:8443,PROXY \
   -p feature=+http2 \
   -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
   -s malloc,18g \
   -s file,/opt/cache/varnish/cache,92g
But I'm a little embarrassed to put the vcl in public because it's used in production for one of my customers and contain some information that should (in my opinion) not be public.
Going back to the 60LTS is an option, but as it is in production I will do it only if the problem is impacting the production as it happen only once at the moment.

Comment: Can you try removing the `-s file,/opt/cache/varnish/cache,92g`? The `file` stevedore is unreliable and causes disk fragmentation at a certain point. Let me know if things work with `malloc` storage only.

Comment: I can try this .. I will give you an update if I encounter some problem

Comment: The full panic string would have been helpful to understand the issue.